# how to write following query in cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

```
SELECT categories.category_name, categories.status, experts.name, experts.email, expert_categories.category_id, expert_categories.expert_id 
FROM categories, experts, expert_categories 
WHERE expert_categories.category_id = categories.id AND expert_categories.expert_id = experts.id AND categories.status = 'A'
```

Comment: I do not have any idea to do it.

Comment: I am new in cakephp

Comment: In which case you should spend some time reading the docs. Try looking at how to [retrieve data in CakePHP 2](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you know what you want then go with prepared statement:

```
 $db = $this->Category->getDataSource(); // if you make function in categories controller
 // $db = $this->getDataSource(); // if you make function in any model

 $result = $db->fetchAll("SELECT categories.category_name,categories.status,
       experts.name, experts.email, expert_categories.category_id, 
       expert_categories.expert_id FROM categories, experts, expert_categories 
       WHERE expert_categories.category_id = categories.id AND
       expert_categories.expert_id = experts.id AND categories.status = 'A'");

 // debug($result);
```

*That is why cakephp prepared statement are made.*

See here: [Cakephp2 prepared statement](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Comment: You are welcome,and if that answer works, you can accept that by clicking correct icon of left side of the answer.

Comment: I found the perfetc solution

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->Category->ExpertCategory->bindModel(array('belongsTo' => array(
    'Category' => array(
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'type'=>'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.id = ExpertCategory.category_id
             ExpertCategory.category_id = ' . $cat_id . ' and 
             Category.status = "A"'
         )
    ),
    'Expert' => array(
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'type'=>'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Expert.id = ExpertCategory.expert_id'
         )
     )
)), false);        

$allExpertArr = $this->Category->ExpertCategory->find('all');
```